# Handling large amounts of requests on IIS and MVC ASP.NET

Tags: iis, mvc

I have a server that loggs different things from various web pages. This server recieves a large amount of requests at all times of the day. All of the requests is a "fire and forget" requests. Therefore the server returns out of the action as fast as possible. I have run a few tests where i log the amount of time the client side uses and the time that is used in the action. The action in the server always used around 5ms before it exits, but the klient side went up to around 2 seconds after running a couple of minutes.

My theory is that IIS can't handle the amount of requests. The IIS has been set up with a default configuration. Therefore I wonder if there is anything I can do on the IIS to optimize for handling large amounts of short lived requests?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK

Every http request have a property named as Timeout, you can reduce it so connections will have less time so you can make quick connections in less time.

and maximum number of connections is also one of the parameter which can help you.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to discard the requests by setting the connection timeout lower. If the default for max concurrent connections is that number, there is no way i can exceed that. Is there any other way? I have read about maximum concurrent requests pr processor, but i am unsure if setting that will help.